# Move files to a directory

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am using a Cordova file plugin to create a folder in the file system of devices. This is working.

My issue is I need to move the audio files to the created directory. How can I achieve that?

Below is my code:

```
function FeedVoicesave(callback, appendData) {
    OnCallback = callback;
    OnAppendData = appendData;
    window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, FeedVoicefail);

}


function gotFS(fileSystem) {
     // create new folder if not exist
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Myfolder", { create: true }, gotDir);
}

   // I have audio file myaudio, i need to move myaudio  to Myfolder
function gotDir(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile(myaudio,null, OnGetFeedVoiceFile);
}
```